# R Tricks for dealing with 0/0 and NaNs

Tags: r, nan

I have two Gaussian functions for which certain values I am dividing then using the resulting values for if-else statements and integration. As both go to 0 fairly quickly, I eventually get 0/0 which R returns as NaN. This yields errors in the code. Aside from getting greater precision from say Rmpfr, I was wondering how one might go about dealing with stuff that results in 0/0 or NaN.

Edit: Here is the code I'm using for greater clarity

```
parameters=c(1,1,2)
R<-function(params,z.){
    params[2]*exp(-z.^2/(2*params[3]^2))
}

alpha<-function(params,z.,v.){
    1/v.[2]*exp(-(z.-v.[1])^2/(2*v.[2]))
}

total.rel.alpha<-function(params,z.,u.){
    final=0
    species.number<-dim(u.)[1]
    if(is.null(dim(u.))){
        return(alpha(params,z.,u.)/R(params,z.))
    }
    for(i in 1:species.number){
        final=final+alpha(params,z.,u.[i,])
    }
    return(final/R(params,z.))
}

Kz<-function(params,z.,v.,u.){
    if(total.rel.alpha(params,z.,u.)>=0 & total.rel.alpha(params,z.,u.)<=1){
        alpha(params,z.,v.)
    }else if(total.rel.alpha(params,z.,u.)>1){
        alpha(params,z.,v.)/total.rel.alpha(params,z.,u.)
    }
}

K<-function(params,v.,u.){
    integrate(Kz,-Inf,Inf,params=params,v.=v.,u.=u.)$value
}
```

If I run:

```
K(parameters, c(1,1), c(1,1))
```

I get

```
Error in integrate(Kz, -Inf, Inf, params = params, v. = v., u. = u.) :   non-finite function value
```

I think this is because at the tails I get 0/0 in total.rel.alpha

Comment: The reason I'm not immediately jumping into coding is that there is not really a problem description,, just failing code. Functions passed to  `integrate` need to be "vectorized". There is a `Vectorize` function that sometimes succeeds in converting function into vectorized versions. (The `alpha`-function does appear to already be vectorized.) Furthermore if you just run the body of the Kz function you get "object 'u.' not found" and it's unclear how that was supposed to be obtained.

Comment: K(parameters, c(0,1), c(0,1)) works. It returns a result (albeit with warning messages but a result nonetheless).

Comment: So ... problem mostly solved? If you would describe the problem and dataflow in your functions I'm sure we could figure out how to get rid of the warnings. I nominated for reopening, since I think there is now enough specific material to work with.

Comment: @42- I actually think it works now. I did the vectorization and cleaned up the code so no more warnings. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So far I'm the only reopen voter but if I get any others it could get reopened and you could post an answer. Maybe @MrFlick will join us. I think you can cast a reopen vote as well.

Comment: @42- Oh I'm not sure I can nor do I know how to cast a reopen vote.

Comment: If it's available it should be right next to the `edit` "button" below your question body on the left.

Answer (score 2):

Work with log(p1/p2) where p1 and p2 are the Gaussian densities in question. You will get a difference of quadratic terms plus some other stuff.

Taking logarithms is a standard approach for working with very small but nonzero probability values.

Comment: @42- ...in my defense I can only say that I recognized my mistake and removed my comment a few minutes after I posted it. Then I asked to please ignore it.

Comment: @RobertDodier so how would I go about modifying my (just added) code to make it work?